# Data Type Conversions in SQL Server Data Import Wizard

Tags: sql-server, excel, import, wizard

**What I'm Doing**

I'm using the Import and Export Wizard in SQL Server 2012 to import data from one tab in a complex spreadsheet. The tab has a lot of data.

I want to import the raw data from the tab into a staging table in the database, and from there run SQL scripts to transform (normalise) the data and load it to its final schema.

In the mapping dialog, I have set all destination columns to NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL (or alternatively NTEXT NULL).

[image: Screenshot of mapping dialog showing all columns set to nvarchar max.]

I'm happy to import everything as text as I'll deal with data type conversion and normalisation once the data is loaded to the staging table.

**The Problem**

The wizard is complaining that some of the column types cannot be converted. It seems to be taking guesses about the data type of the source, and is refusing to convert columns which it thinks are doubles.

[image: Screenshot showing wizard complaining about double types.]

[image: Screenshot of the error message.]

I don't care at all what data type it thinks the source is. I want it to treat everything as text. However, there does not seem to be any way to change the wizard's guess about the source column type, or to force it to import the data anyway.

The wizard will not allow me to run the package.

**Problem Boundary**

I'm only interested in solving the extract portion of the problem, i.e. how to get the data from the spreadsheet into the temporary table. What I do with it once it's extracted is a separate problem, and I'm happy to have everything sitting in NVARCHARs or NTEXTs at the staging level.

**Desired Solution**

I want to get the data from the spreadsheet into a staging table, from where I can perform other work on it. I'm happy to have everything in the staging table as string data. I do not care at all what data type the wizard thinks it's importing, I have already specified the output type that I want in the destination table.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that use SSIS instead of import/export SQL Server wizard in first. you can also change cell format on source to numeric instead of text.

Comment: Good idea. This may be my next step.